# Platinum trophy achievement script using playerprefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have global achievements working using IEnumerator based on number of clicks on different game objects to earn each achievement. Now I want to enable a platinum trophy that will auto-populate when the other trophies have all been earned. Looking for suggestions on proper script to use.

Below is a sample from my existing globalachievements, but since earning is based on # of clicks on single game objects, not sure what code to use to get the platinum trophy going since it's not click-triggered.

```
//general variables
public GameObject achNote;
public AudioSource achSound;
public bool achActive = false;
public GameObject achTitle;
public GameObject achDesc;

IEnumerator Trigger01Ach()
{
    achActive = true;
    ach01Code = 12345;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Ach01", ach01Code);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Ach01", 1);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    achSound.Play();
    ach01Image.SetActive(true);
    achTitle.GetComponent<Text>().text = "ACE ANGLER";
    achDesc.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Go Fish";
    achNote.SetActive(true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);

//Resetting UI
    achNote.SetActive(false);
    ach01Image.SetActive(false);
    achTitle.GetComponent<Text>().text = "";
    achDesc.GetComponent<Text>().text = "";
    achActive = false;
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags. Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code rather looks like `c#`.

Comment: In general what is `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Ach01", ach01Code); PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Ach01", 1);` supposed to do? You are just two times overwriting the same value => it will always be saved with value `1` ...